# Python class that implements the Newton method

Tags: python, optimization, mathematics, numerical-methods

Here is a python function I wrote to implement the Newton method for optimization for the case where you are trying to optimize a function that takes a vector input and gives a scalar output.  I use numdifftools to approximate the hessian and the gradient of the given function then perform the newton method iteration.

```
import numpy as np
import numdifftools as nd

class multivariate_newton(object):

    def __init__(self,func,start_point,step_size=0.8,num_iter=100,tol=0.000001):
        '''
        func: function to be optimized. Takes a vector argument as input and returns
              a scalar output
        step_size: step size in newton method update step
        num_iter: number of iterations for newton method to run
        tol: tolerance to determine convergence
        '''
        self.func=func
        self.start_point=np.array(start_point)
        self.num_iter=num_iter
        self.step_size=step_size
        self.tol=tol


    def newton_method(self):
        '''
        perform multivariate newton method for function with vector input
        and scalar output
        '''
        x_t=self.start_point
        #Get an approximation to hessian of function
        H=nd.Hessian(self.func)
        #Get an approximation of Gradient of function
        g=nd.Gradient(self.func)

        for i in range(self.num_iter):
            x_tplus1=x_t-self.step_size*np.dot(np.linalg.inv(H(x_t)),g(x_t))
            #check for convergence
            if abs(max(x_tplus1-x_t))<self.tol:
                break
            x_t=x_tplus1

        self.crit_point=x_tplus1
        self.max_min=self.func(x_t)

        return self

    def critical_point(self):
        '''
        print critical point found in newton_method function. newton_method function
        must be called first.
        '''
        print self.crit_point
```

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong with the functions in [`scipy.optimize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.html)?

Comment: I could not find one for the case of a function with vector input and scalar output.  I tried fsolve but it would only work with vector input/output functions.  Now that I look again, 'root' may work.  I will give it a try.

Comment: nevermind, 'root' required the input and output dimensions to be the same which is not what I want

Comment: This would better be a function instead of a class.

Comment: I'm not sure what is commonly done here but I think you can avoid computing the inverse of the Hessian directly, which may be more costly and less numerically accurate (see [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pathological cases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Failure_analysis) exist where Newton's method will not converge on a solution.  Yet, there is no obvious way for the caller to tell whether convergence was achieved.  You should distinguish between whether the loop terminated via the `break` (success) or by exhaustion of the loop condition (failure).

```
for _ in range(self.num_iter):
    x_tplus1 = x_t - self.step_size * np.dot(np.linalg.inv(H(x_t)), g(x_t))
    #check for convergence
    if abs(max(x_tplus1-x_t))<self.tol:
        break
    x_t = x_tplus1
else:
    raise SolutionNotFound, "No convergence after %d iterations" % (self.num_iter)
```